# Extract a pattern from all the lines in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string variable that looks like this -

```
string Output = "C:\src\Hello1.txt -> C:\Temp\hewvjke\Hello1.txt
    C:\src\Hello.txt -> C:\Temp\hewvjke\Hello.txt
    2 File(s) copied";
```

Basically it contains `"<source file> -> <destination file>"` n times.

I want a regular expression that can extract the list of destination files.

I want the output variable to be something like this

```
string afterRegex = "C:\Temp\hewvjke\Hello1.txt
C:\Temp\hewvjke\Hello.txt
    2 File(s) copied"
```

How can i do this?

Comment: So the first snippet is not code but a string literal?

Comment: What does your current code do?

Comment: Is there any return character between the ends of paths in the source output?

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:** i think you have a file ex: `myfile` contains following 3 Lines with

```
 ==source path==       ==destination path==
C:\src\Hello1.txt -> C:\Temp\hewvjke\Hello1.txt
C:\src\Hello.txt -> C:\Temp\hewvjke\Hello.txt
    2 File(s) copied
```

you want to Remove the Source path from the above file content.
so expected output should be as below:

```
 C:\Temp\hewvjke\Hello1.txt
 C:\Temp\hewvjke\Hello.txt
      2 File(s) copied
```

**Program:**

```
            String[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("myfile.txt");
            String[] newLines = new String[lines.Length];
            int i=0;
            foreach (String line in lines)
            {
                newLines[i]=(line.Contains(">"))?line.Split('>')[1]:line;
                 i++;
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("myfile.txt",newLines);
```

**Output:** after executing the above statements `myfile` contains following Text:

```
C:\Temp\hewvjke\Hello1.txt
C:\Temp\hewvjke\Hello.txt
        2 File(s) copied
```

Note: Please let me know if you want to do something else.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Thank you sir, i have added my assumption please correct me if im wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Code...

```
string inputMessage = @"C:\src\Hello1.txt -> C:\Temp\hewvjke\Hello1.txt
                        C:\src\Hello.txt -> C:\Temp\hewvjke\Hello.txt
                        2 File(s) copied";
string outputMessage = Regex.Replace(inputMessage, @".* -> " , "");
```

Good Luck!